# Recursively flatten specific property of object

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following type I want to write a type that recursively removes sys, metadata and flattens fields

Input:

```
{
    sys: {
        id: string;
    };
    metadata: {
        author: string;
    };
    fields: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        father: {
            sys: {
                id: string;
            };
            metadata: {
                author: string;
            };
            name: string;
        },
        siblings: {
            sys: {
                id: string;
            };
            metadata: {
                author: string;
            };
            name: string;
        }[]
    };
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
    name: string;
    age: number;
    father: {
        name: string;
    };
    siblings: {
        name: string;
    }[];
}
```

My approach was to check whether key is sys or metadata and then return never. But I haven't been able to figure out how to infer the value of fields and just merge it with the given object:

```
type Helper<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends "sys" | "metadata"
        ? never
        : K extends "fields"
        ? ...
        : T[K] extends Array<infer I>
        ? I extends object
            ? Helper<I>
            : never
        : T[K] extends object
        ? Helper<T[K]>
        : T[K];
};
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wEpJ2W) meet your needs? Please test thoroughly before you respond; these sorts of deeply recursive types tend to have LOTS of edge cases.  If it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need 4 cases here.

1. If the type as an array, prune the members of that array.
2. If the object has a `fields` object, then just use the value of `T['fields']`
3. If the value is an object, then execute the the steps again with each property that is not `'sys' | 'metadata'`
4. Omit the type if none of the above apply (a primitive value)

Then call that recursively.

This type does that:

```
type Helper<T> =
  // If array, map array members and resolve to an array
  T extends unknown[] ? Helper<T[number]>[] :

  // If this object has `fields`, then use that.
  T extends { fields: unknown } ? Helper<T['fields']> :

  // If this is an object, then remove unwanted keys and recurse each property
  T extends object ? { [K in Exclude<keyof T, 'sys' | 'metadata'>]: Helper<T[K]> } :

  // No other checks applied, use the value as is.
  T
```

Which works as you expect:

```
const obj: Helper<Input> = {
  name: '',
  age: 123,
  father: { name: 'asd' },
  siblings: [{ name: 'qwe' }]
} // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvAUFXUDOI+AXJjnhQJYAmp+wATpXAOYDc5uAvhxQLYRgAQ2pDhpbBQpDkACwD2DOo2btOUHuoBmlCABtqJMlLxwhA5U1a8TUISwik4iPgCMIDGya1jZHieq2BEQBQUE0lqpeYZpheALCouLGcVIywApKBCrWgbaxqWYW2VZqQVwANHm4+JSueqpGkqmETdVhESVR7RQFcQkiYkKhqdJyipG5o31hRY5dU-kA2gC66ppcWFigkFAAogAekADGwBDUaCm4c5NlePbzzm4e0T4Z-ldSNwt33NG19UaIxM33opWiXFWHE223A0AAEvpIAwADwAFQAfGhyGioBADmc4IYoIg4ABrODyADucFWUAA-FBEXpkeilk93AwVhi6cQcXiCRAifhMFAdPpDKRSRTqXANAymUiPGyAOTigz4FXcqB83C4-GE4nyVwAKwgpwVGCgSwA0lBmPsDsc9IhqBAUWSICB5FooGiKlAVa0VVAAD6BgZJIQqjErUjM1lo23arg6nFbLY7aBoiD0S4J5XwJDALEGoXEw4nM4XRmMRDQUg+PT4CBYAD0bbwAD16VtjvI4HnjSb40rUUXkFj0M1viqVVVcA9SABGABMAGYF2LfB8rbOhPhqCHKuQAQ1WEYlnvzPMVQBHKkQY9rVMdsXMCBAA)

Answer (score 0):

After removing your `sys` and `metadata` properties, you can check again if the initial object had those properties and, if it did, intersect your result with the type in that property.

To remove those properties, instead of using `never` you should use the approach used by the built-in [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type:

```js
/**
 * Construct a type with the properties of T except for those in type K.
 */
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

It looks to me like you need this to work recursively, but since your example in your question is not valid TypeScript code I'm not entirely sure if this is *exactly* what you want. But hopefully it's at least close enough that you can make minor tweaks to make it suit your purpose.

I've included an example object at the end to show the shape that results from this `Helper` type implementation:

```js
type Example = {
    sys: {
        id: string;
    };
    metadata: {
        author: string;
    };
    fields: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        father: {
            sys: {
                id: string;
            };
            metadata: {
                author: string;
            };
            name: string;
        },
        siblings: {
            sys: {
                id: string;
            };
            metadata: {
                author: string;
            };
            name: string;
        }[]
    };
};

type Helper<T extends Object> = {
  [K in Exclude<keyof T, 'sys' | 'metadata'>]: T[K] extends Object ? Helper<T[K]> : T[K]
} & (
  'sys' extends keyof T
    ? T['sys'] extends Object ? Helper<T['sys']> : T['sys']
    : {}
) & (
  'metadata' extends keyof T
    ? T['metadata'] extends Object ? Helper<T['metadata']> : T['metadata']
    : {}
);

type TransformedExample = Helper<Example>;

const transformedExample: TransformedExample = {
  id: 'id',
  author: 'author',
  fields: {
    name: 'name',
    age: 1,
    father: {
      id: 'fatherId',
      author: 'fatherAuthor',
      name: 'fatherName',
    },
    siblings: [{
      id: 'siblingId',
      author: 'siblingAuthor',
      name: 'siblingName',
    }],
  },
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQN4CgoFQDOIRAXDvodQJYAmFRwATjQHYDmA3FQQL49qSCMAR0EoinmrUEAV2AALAPbNGLdt15QB2gGY0IqOuUozCbZBHWtOg81AQdrUNnKQAjCM3vm9ExW8pbQdiUmDQ0PobTV9I3UjCYVFxSTNEmXklVRi7EIcEjMthXK1QvgAafIIiGg9UTVNpDJIm6sjo4g08jJ040OSxCQQI3sIslTUu2zKMwsTilyYZ-sI+AG0AXW1dXVxQSCgACSNIZgAeABUoCDhgCDYTKAB5DwArCABjYAA+KCxmusANJQdiwOCfVByOgQc4AawgIGUeiglwqUAA5K0MVAAD6YwapBAYn6bCiXYGbG53B5PV4fb5QAD8x1O3iulL+5MpuD4UAAZFAABRULGkHG3e6PIhQBFIlGXbQsiliogYqmS2ky+lfYDM1moM4c1Xqrmo9Ym7bUKR8XAASgFwtFhOGEpp0tliORqKV5oxLtE6upUrp711+pOhvZKoDxM2ZpjIiGgathBt9p4+3A0EuzAQbCIelUwjo8GQaEwBqNZZQ6B+mc+ygLepY+cLxYgpcQtZcubbReYJZrFf+6U6GPoGKqBAmOUxs+YU6oBiMJlGBEWFAxiyXsmcFAAjNPCP4lEF0rQGJjT4FmABJOi7zIKSZbm-eACCL9UT+om+vATeAAclYv46MeNR1A0nCmOszSXlutT1JoD5gTO35TFiUGaF+2SLhBFhWIh2GcCBwhgXwmzHpUvI8EAA)

I'm not sure if you also need to flatten the `sys` and `metadata` properties, as I've done in this example, but if you don't you can simplify these bits...

`T['sys'] extends Object ? Helper<T['sys']> : T['sys']`

...to just be `T['sys']` for example.